# How to choose Session Store depending on active Profile in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session

In a Spring Boot 3.2 application I want to choose which session store is being used, depending on active profiles.

In older Spring Boot versions there was a property to set:

```yaml
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
```

So if you want to use redis instead, just override this value in the depending profile properties.

However, this property is no longer available. Since I can't think that Spring Boot creators wants to make life harder for us developers, I'm wondering what the current way to go is.

[Spring Session](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.1/reference/htmlsingle/#web.spring-session) by default has now an order for choosing a specific implementation when there are more than one session implementations available.

My question is: How can I tell Spring Boot which session management to use depending on an active profile?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to provide the configuration explicitly.
Something like this:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
public class JdbcSessionConfig {
    // JDBC session configuration
}

@Configuration
@Profile("test")
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class RedisSessionConfig {
    // Redis session configuration
}
```

Comment: That sounds good. Can you give the code for the required session configurations? I can't find anything for that in the Spring Boot documentations. Or if there is something, maybe you can give a link to that? As mentioned in the original question, I'm not willing to accept that Spring Boot development is made harder by default, so there either must be a simple solution equivalent to setting a property flag or at least a simple way to copy paste a code snippet which will do the work. At least I'm not that expert to pull such a thing off by snipping my fingers ;)

Comment: Another question: How can I have the session dependencies in place but tell Spring Boot to refrain from configuring them? So to achieve the same as former setting the `store-type` to `none`?

Comment: I don't think it makes your spring boot implementation complicated, it just provides more control over session configuration, and since you want to use a particular session based on profile this solution can be useful. 

You can check this link to look at how the session can be configured as a bean:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-tutorial



Regarding your second question, if I get it correctly you can exclude autoconfiguration this way: 
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SessionAutoConfiguration.class})

Comment: Thank you for the link, and especially for telling how to exclude `SessionAutoConfiguration`. I think I can work with these information, although I still think the former way to configure the whole thing via application properties was easier. Anyhow, somtimes you just have to go the extra mile...